# Can't insert into a database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

For learning purposes, I am creating a password manager on my local system. However there is a problem when it comes to inserting data into the database and I'm not sure why it isn't working.

My entire document can be the found below.

```php
<?php

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db   = 'accounts';
    $server = 'localhost';

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);

    if (!$db_handle) {
        echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $db_found = mysql_select_db($db, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
            $getOrSet = $_POST['type'];
            $site = $_POST['site'];
            $login = $_POST['login'];
            if ($getOrSet == 'get') {
                $pass = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT password FROM manager WHERE site = '$site' AND username = '$login'"))['password'];
            } else if ($getOrSet == 'set') {
                $url = $_POST['url'];
                $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO manager (site, url, username, password) VALUES ('$site', '$url', '$login' '$pass')");
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "Unable to select database: " . mysql_error();
    }
    mysql_close($db_handle);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            #left,#right{width:50%;margin:0;padding:0;float:left;text-align:center}
            form{width:300px;margin:0 auto}
            label{width:300px;display:block;line-height:1.65em}
            input{float:right}
            #pass{width:300px}
            #pass>span{float:right}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Password Manager</h1>
        <div id="left">
            <h2>Get Password</h2>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <label>Site: <input type="text" name="site" /></label>
                <label>Email/Username: <input type="text" name="login" /></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="get" />
                <?php if(isset($_POST['type'])){if ($getOrSet == 'get') {echo "<span id=\"pass\">Password: <span>$pass</span></span>";}} ?>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <h2>Set Password</h2>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <label>Site: <input type="text" name="site" /></label>
                <label>URL: <input type="text" name="url" /></label>
                <label>Email/Username: <input type="text" name="login" /></label>
                <label>Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="set" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please tell me why this code doesn't work?

```php
mysql_query("INSERT INTO manager (site, url, username, password) VALUES ('$site', '$url', '$login' '$pass')");
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: append `or die(mysql_error())` like `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and see what error comes

Comment: @hjpotter92 As this is just for me, I couldn't care less if they are deprecated or not, Just as long as they work.

Comment: Then start escaping the variables you use in the query.

Comment: @SKRocks I get this error, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". There are only 4 columns in the table so I don't exactly understand what this means.

Comment: @Spedwards - you mentioned you're learning. Is there any particular tutorial that you're following? If yes, could you post the link?

Comment: @N.B. No specific tutorial. And I'm not exactly learning in any particular order either.

Comment: @Spedwards use escapes i think you are trying to insert date with "," or etct. try my answer

Comment: There are many bad things you've done with that code. The reason people tell you that you shouldn't use deprecated functions is not because someone decided to create new thing that only hipsters will use. The newer mechanisms (PDO) actually lets you write LESS code that's instantly secure against any possible SQL injections (note that SQL injection isn't always about an attack, lots of sql injections produce problems in regular algorithm flow). You also haven't showed us what the input you used was, so just by looking at the code - no one can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: So to conclude that long comment, show us the input you've used to perform those queries. It appears one of your inputs has `'` character inside it, causing the query to fail in some way.

Comment: Well the "Get Password" section works and my inputs for "Set" are: Gmail, http://gmail.com, myemail@gmail.com, myAlphaNumericPass. So there an no `'`s

Comment: @N.B. It wasn't a `'` getting added but a missing `,` after `'$login'`

Comment: I'm sure the answer to the following question will depend on the person but which is better to use, mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @Spedwards - PDO, hands down. It's got nicer interface. Naturally, this is personal opinion.

Answer (score 3):

use escapes before insert like

```
$site = mysql_real_escape_string($site);
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($url);
$login = mysql_real_escape_string($login);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);

// now insert 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO manager (site, url, username, password) VALUES ('$site', '$url', '$login', '$pass')");
```

**Note :** `mysql_*` is deprecated. `use mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: @hd. oh sorry bro typing mistake

Comment: I tried this just before you posted and doesn't work. Though I did `$site = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['site']);` but I don't see any real difference.

Comment: @Spedwards Then look at the documentation as to what mres will do.

Comment: @Spedwards try my code. then see what happened. i will definitly help u

Comment: Still getting the same error, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: Oh wow... Such a small thing but I just noticed there is no comma after `'$login'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a missing `,` after `'$login'` so

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO manager (site, url, username, password) VALUES ('$site', '$url', '$login' '$pass')");
```

should have been

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO manager (site, url, username, password) VALUES ('$site', '$url', '$login', '$pass')")
```